# firebase databasereference gives no virtual method error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add firebase database some info by getting database reference but it gives the fallowing error:

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzckb()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.bogroup.ucuncuprogram-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes25.dex)

My java code is lke the fallowing:

```
package com.bogroup.ucuncuprogram;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import static com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext;

public class database{

    private Firebase mRootRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    public void kullanicikontrol(String kullaniciadi){
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase.child("users").child(kullaniciadi).setValue("9999999");
        //chieldref.setValue("9999999");

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = kullaniciadi;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

What may be the problem, thanks in advance.

My app build.grade is like fallowing:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bogroup.ucuncuprogram"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
        // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
        // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.2.4'
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    //compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you upgrade your firebase gradle version to 11.0.0?

Comment: Post your app module build.gradle

Comment: edited my post to add build.grade file.

Comment: `firebase-ui:0.4.4` ... That definitely needs updated

Comment: In addition to cricket's answer about consistent versions, there are potential problems mixing the legacy SDK with the new SDK.  It is safer to remove `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.2.4` and use only the new SDK libs, `com.google.firebase:firebase-*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your versions of Firebase and Firebase UI need to [line up according to the table on their Github Page](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries).

For reference, should you choose to upgrade (I would highly recommend it).

> **FirebaseUI Version**
>   1.2.0
>
> **Firebase/Play Services Version**
>   10.2.0

Easy way to do this

```
ext {
    googlePlayVer = "10.2.0"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // For example
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${googlePlayVer}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${googlePlayVer}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${googlePlayVer}"
```